# How to create new website with new url on Magento 2.3.5

Tags: magento2

i want to create a new website, default website has url "abc.com"

I want to create new website with new url is "xyz.com"

How to do it, i followed [**How to Setup Magento 2 with Multiple Stores and Domains**](https://www.simicart.com/blog/magento-2-multiple-stores-domains/) but it not work for me

And i try add this code to .htaccess, it also not work, please help me

```
SetEnvIf Host www\.abc\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=abc_web
SetEnvIf Host www\.abc\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^abc\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=abc_web
SetEnvIf Host ^abc\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website

SetEnvIf Host www\.xyz\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=xyz_web
SetEnvIf Host www\.xyz\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^xyz\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=xyz_web
SetEnvIf Host ^xyz\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are managing multistore, then create a folder for the store on root directory and in that folder, create index.php and .htaccess file, after that you can add magerun code in that index.php file.